# How can we configure IIS for domain name mapping

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I would like to configure IIS server at (Windows server 2003) for domain name mapping.

We have purchased domain name for one of our newly created website.

I would like to know how can I configure IIS so that anybody from outside world can reach website by typing URL.

As in: `http://example.com/` should redirect to my the home page of my website.

I have made website in using ASP.NET and Oracle.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not programming related, try http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your domain on a DNS server, which is different (though could be the same physical box) as your IIS server. Long time since I've done this myself, as I use a hosting company for this kind of thing, but you will typically need at least two DNS Server IP addresses typically for a domain (primary and secondary DNS servers). There is a DNS Server for the windows server platform, but most people use hosting services to do this thing.

By the way, you might get a better response posting this kind of question on serverfault.com, as it's not really a developer question.